# Python dict.get() raises KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am getting lost here, Python 2.7, I have a dictionary `mt`, and I use the `get()` method, which by documentation says:

> `get(key[, default])` Return the value for key if key is in the
>   dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to
>   None, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

but I still get

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/subscription-workers/commands/dr/rebilling.py", line 48, in rebill
    if mt.get('is_rebill', 0) == 1:
 KeyError: 'is_rebill'
```

Any ideas why?

The `mt` is a normal `dict`, that sometimes does not have the key.

Comment: Can you show us what mt looks like

Comment: That syntax hasn't errors, you should show your `mt` dict as @TimCastelijns says, but it seems you don't have a key called 'is_rebill' in your dict

Comment: Doesn't matter, a KeyError shouldn't be raised when using `get()`

Comment: its working for me in python2.7 and not raising any `KeyError`.

Comment: `mt` is not a `dict`. Use `print type(mt))` and check the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I nailed the problem down. Before this code was put in place there was this one

```
File "/home/ubuntu/subscription-workers/commands/dr/rebilling.py", line 48, in rebill
    if mt['is_rebill'] == 1:
KeyError: 'is_rebill'
```

The problem was that there were .pyc files from the older version, but the stack trace was loading the actual code. After running

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

and reloading the app everything was fine and without problems.

Comment: Using `-rf` is asking for trouble. The `-r` is for recursive delete, which should not be needed if one is just asking to delete files (not directories) and `-f` can obscure files that should be deleted but can't be because of permissions.  As someone pointed out, `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete` also works.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mt = {'key1' : 1}
>>> mt.get('is_rebill', 0)
0
```

It does not generates key error if key is not present it returns 0

```
>>> mt.update({'is_rebill':1})
>>> mt.get('is_rebill', 0)
1

>>> if mt.get('is_rebill', 0) == 1:
...     print True
... else:
...     print False
... 
False
```

Comment: @Down voter please comment your reason for down vote.

Comment: how does this answer the question? it is a comment at best

Comment: Well the question was KeyError based on dictionaries inbuilt function get. So i tried to show that it doesn't generates KeyError when we use dict get function so it might be related to some other issues.

Comment: the OP has added the part of the docs that states there should be no key error using .get so  your answer does not does not add anything to the question, without seeing  what mt is the question is unanswerable and should be closed.

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed instead we could have tried  to ask more information about OP's question and help him out.

Comment: why did you not ask the OP for more information then?

Comment: It was not my suggestion to close the question. I tried my best by trying to answering the question in some way instead of closing the question.

Comment: The question cannot be answered because the OP has not provided reproducible code, your answer is not an answer because it does not solve the problem, the problem is unsolvable without seeing what mt is and the code and context it is used in .

Comment: I am agree with your down vote opinion. But i don't agree to close the question without asking for more information from OP. If op fails to provide sufficient information related to question then i agree that it should to closed.

Comment: people have commented and asked for more information but really when you ask a question on SO this information should be included, questions can be reopened if the necessary information is provided. I think closing the question is a way to actually encourage people to write good questions that include all the relevant information

Comment: Your comment was really helpful because I didn't knew that we can reopen once the question is closed.