# Python os.environ throws key error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm accessing an environment variable in a script with `os.environ.get` and it's throwing a `KeyError`. It doesn't throw the error from the Python prompt. This is running on OS X 10.11.6, and is Python 2.7.10.

What is going on?

```
$ python score.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "score.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_logging()
  File "/score/log.py", line 29, in setup_logging
    config = get_config()
  File "/score/log.py", line 11, in get_config
    environment = os.environ.get('NODE_ENV')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'NODE_ENV'
$ python -c "import os; os.environ.get('NODE_ENV')"
$
```

**As requested, here's the source code for `score.py`**

```
from __future__ import print_function

from log import get_logger, setup_logging
setup_logging()
log = get_logger('score')
```

**And here's `log.py`**

```
import json
import os
import sys

from iron_worker import IronWorker
from logbook import Logger, Processor, NestedSetup, StderrHandler, SyslogHandler

IRON_IO_TASK_ID = IronWorker.task_id()

def get_config():
  environment = os.environ.get('NODE_ENV')
  if environment == 'production':
    filename = '../config/config-production.json'
  elif environment == 'integration':
    filename = '../config/config-integration.json'
  else:
    filename = '../config/config-dev.json'

  with open(filename) as f:
    return json.load(f)

def setup_logging():
  # This defines a remote Syslog handler
  # This will include the TASK ID, if defined
  app_name = 'scoreworker'
  if IRON_IO_TASK_ID:
    app_name += '-' + IRON_IO_TASK_ID

  config = get_config()

  default_log_handler = NestedSetup([
    StderrHandler(),
    SyslogHandler(
      app_name,
      address = (config['host'], config['port']),
      level = 'ERROR',
      bubble = True
    )
  ])
  default_log_handler.push_application()

def get_logger(name):
  return Logger(name)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `score.py`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: That's bizarre. `get` should never throw a `KeyError`; it's supposed to return `None` if the key isn't found (or whatever default you provided if you provided one). Heck, the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py#l91) for that method isn't even supposed to have a `raise KeyError(key)` line in it at all!

Comment: Interesting enigma, could you give us a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can also have some fun?

Comment: @user2357112 That source code is useless. `os.environ` is **not** a `dict`. It's a class implemented in C and is not a `UserDict` subclass.

Comment: @Bakuriu: You sure about that? [It looks like a `UserDict` subclass to me](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py#l413), and inspecting it in interactive mode says it's descended from `UserDict`.

Comment: What OS is this on?  `os.environ` seems to be defined in a number of different ways depending on the OS.  In any event, this seems really strange as it is pointing to UserDict.py line 23 in `__getitem__` -- However, line 23 in `UserDict.py` doesn't have anything to do with `__getitem__`...  What major/minor version of python are you using?

Comment: Is this IronPython or something? I'm not familiar with what `iron_worker` is.

Comment: IronWorker is a utility class for iron.io. This is running on OS X,with Python 2.7.10.

Comment: @user2357112 - it's a client for the `iron.io` service.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist -- Right, that's why I was asking for the `sys.version` information :-).  It isn't that way in the [latest python2.7 branch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py#l23)...

Comment: I think `iron.io` might be affecting your environment variables. Maybe you're in a worker process with a different environment or something. It's still weird that you'd get a KeyError from `get`, though.

Comment: Could you be experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26906934/3642398? I didn't know this could happen (stacktrace showing current code, but executing code from `.pyc` file), but seems to be what that user is describing.

Comment: @user2357112 -- It's also odd that there is no mention of `UserDict.get` in the traceback ... Generally, `.get()` should end up _calling_ `__getitem__`.

Comment: @ChrisB. Have you already confirmed that setting the env var properly (or just force it with some dummy data) as suggested in my answer made any difference? If it's so, could you confirm?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist -- Yeah, that's what it looks like on my local python install too (2.7.10).  But the weird thing is that [`UserDict.get`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b36cb4602e21/Lib/UserDict.py#l58) (line 61 in UserDict.py) _should_ be in the traceback -- But I'm not seeing it.  It's almost like someone monkey patched `UserDict.get = UserDict.__getitem__`, but that would be a really shady thing to do...

Comment: Note that `os` may use [a different UserDict implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py#l468) depending on the operating system.

Comment: @elethan That turned out to be the issue. The original code (which used `os.environ['NODE_ENV']` was run in Docker, and wrote a `.pyc` file to my local machine with the wrong timestamp. Subsequent tests, which were done on my local machine, used the old compiled code but the new source.

Comment: @ChrisB. great! I was so intrigued by this mystery; it makes my day that I could help solve it, haha! I posted an answer as well, because I thought it was worth a shot. Glad it panned out!

Comment: I am working on Windows, and this helped me solve the issue:                         
 my_api_key = os.getenv('Your api key variable name')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try running:

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

To delete your `.pyc` files.

Researching your problem I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26861856/3642398), where a user was experiencing the same thing: `.get()` seemingly raising a `KeyError`. In that case, it was caused, according to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26906934/3642398), by a `.pyc` file which contained code where a `dict` value was being accessed by key (i.e., `mydict['potentially_nonexistent_key']`), while the traceback was showing the code from the updated `.py` file where `.get()` was used. I have never heard of this happening, where the traceback references current code from a `.py` file, but shows an error raised by an outdated `.pyc` file, but it seems to have happened at least once in the history of Python...

It is a long shot, but worth a try I thought.

Comment: I've seen happen dozen of times, I.e. .pyc that have newer dates from the files. Source control like git can cause it, when you move to older code after you already run it. Also seen case of people putting their .pyc files into repos (which should be avoided with .gitignore)

Comment: @Fruch absolutely. I have gotten burned by related issues, but this particular one was new to me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.. Until I exited and reloaded my IDE after adding environment variable (VS Code)

Comment: Agree with @JGFMK

Answer (score 14):

I encountered a similar error when I set the environment variable without exporting it. So if you do this:

```
me@host:/# NODE_ENV=foo
```

You will get this:

```
me@host:/# python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> node_env = os.environ['NODE_ENV']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'NODE_ENV'
>>>
```

But if you do this:

```
me@host:/# NODE_ENV=foo
me@host:/# export NODE_ENV
```

It works:

```
me@host:/# python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> node_env = os.environ['NODE_ENV']
>>> print(node_env)
foo
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Command for windows to delete the .pyc files:

```
del /S *.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved that by making some corrections on the .env file:

Before:

```
Key = Value
```

After my correction:

```
Key=Value
```

without blank spaces and worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while trying to source from a .env file.
I didn't explicitly export the env vars so I had to change this.

```
ENVIRONMENT=DEV
```

to this

```
export ENVIRONMENT=DEV
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `export a=10` instead of `a=10` while setting env variable. Add the same in ~./bashrc to reload the env var wherever you login.

Doing this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the load_dotenv() function. It is a method provided by the dotenv package in Python and is used to load environment variables from a file with the .env extension and make them available to your Python script as environment variables.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

os.environ['env_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, it turns out there was actually nothing wrong.

What was happening was that since I had turned on the "break on `Any exception`" option for my debugger (PyCharm), it was breaking on exceptions while the code was starting up. Idk why those exceptions were happening, but the errors I was seeing were not actually any for me to worry about.

Setting the `Ignore library files` option solved my issue.

[image: Ignore library files PyCharm debugger option]

Answer (score -6):

I'd recommend you start debugging os.py, for instance, on windows it's being used this implementation:

```
def get(self, key, failobj=None):
    print self.data.__class__
    print key
    return self.data.get(key.upper(), failobj)
```

And if I test it with this:

```
import os


try:
    os.environ.get('NODE_ENV')
except Exception as e:
    print("-->{0}".format(e.__class__))

os.environ['NODE_ENV'] = "foobar"

try:
    os.environ.get('NODE_ENV')
except Exception as e:
    print("{0}".format(e.__class__))
```

The output will be:

```
<type 'dict'>
PYTHONUSERBASE
<type 'dict'>
APPDATA
<type 'dict'>
NODE_ENV
<type 'dict'>
NODE_ENV
```

So it makes sense the exception is not spawned reading [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) docs.

In any case, if you don't want to mess up or debugging the python modules, try cleaning up the *.pyc files, try to set up properly `NODE_ENV`. And if all that don't work, restart your terminal to clear up.

Comment: OP is using `os.environ.get`. _Of course_ this can throw a `KeyError`. That's not controversial or unexpected.

Comment: *“I’ve been able to reproduce the exception with this completely different code”* – How does that help solving OP’s problem?

Comment: @poke Different code? Come on, it's the same exception and i think i gave the solution `Why not trying setting properly that NODE_ENV var?`, confirm that first... and then just downvote, sigh... :P

Comment: I can get the same exception from doing `raise KeyError('NODE_ENV')` – Is that helpful? No. OP is using a very different way to access the environment variable than you, a way that should **not** raise an exception when the key does not exist. That’s the problem that wants to be solved here.

Comment: @poke My point is, at that particular line that error is being raised, right? Ok, solve that first, avoid the exception and then, and just then, try to figure out what's going on, step by step, that was my point.

Comment: But calling `.get` _is_ a way to avoid the exception! And it isn't working.

Comment: Now you're `pop`ping a key that isn't present. That also doesn't have anything to do with the questioner's case, and it would be expected to throw a `KeyError`, while the questioner's code wouldn't.

Comment: @user2357112 Sure, but the easiest question wasn't given yet, has he tried to set that env var just before `get`ting that key to confirm the exception won't be spawned.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The main strategy suggested to the OP (few minutes ago) was collecting more info about his exception. That "hackish" way to avoid it **forcing** the code not spawning the exception was quite helpful. Once he had confirmed that (he didn't), it was just a matter to debug the thing using the underlying python code. Anyway, question was already answered. In any case, I still think my answer would have been quite helpful to him, before even discovering the issue with the *.pyc files