# os.environ producing error recently only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

Recently I had this problem with vscode where `os.environ` isn't working anymore, it used to be able to read the key on the separate `.env` file. This file works perfect on replit, however, when i try downloading it, it can't be run locally

I have tried deleting `.pyc` files, but it's still the same.
[Python os.environ throws key error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280435/python-os-environ-throws-key-error)

Error in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\heroku\Desktop\ricebot\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
  File "C:\Users\heroku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TOKEN'
```

Comment: Isn't that because it can't find the `TOKEN` environment variable?

Comment: @LuisAFK i haven't changed anything to the file, and it used to work a couple of days ago as well

Comment: I would also say, that you don't get the environment variable loaded and therefore you get the KeyError. If you load the `.env` file with `dotenv.load_dotenv()`, try to use explicit paht, like `dotenv.load_dotenv('/paht/to/.env')`. Maybe that helps

Comment: Environment variables come from parent process, not from the individual script you're running (unless that script goes out of its way to assign such a variable), so whether you changed the file has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If your problem is that VS code isn't honoring your .env, that's a VS code question, not a Python question. It isn't Python's job to read `.env` files.