# python cant find the env var

Tags: python-3.x, docker, github-actions

I'm passing env var via docker container run in github actions like so:

```
run: docker container run -d -e MY_KEY="some key" -p 3000:3000 somedockerimage/somedockerimage:0.0.2
```

I know it should pass it right way because it working with node.js

in the python file:

```
import os

api_key = os.environ['MY_KEY']
print(api_key)
```

the results I get:

```
File "print.py", line 4, in <module>
    api_key = os.environ['MY_KEY']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MY_KEY'
```

Comment: did you tried with `os.getenv("MY_KEY")`  instead?

Comment: I did, got same results

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything incorrect with the way you're running your Docker container. It's difficult to say without seeing the rest of the project, but you may need to delete your `.pyc` files with something like `find . -name \*.pyc -delete`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280914/9178159) could add more context.