# dictionary get() throwing key error

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrency, python-asyncio, sanic

I am keeping a naive connection pool using a python dictionary. As reference, I am using *asyncio within Sanic* if that matters.

Not often, but at times, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 556, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/Users/Documents/Project/<proj>/<dir>/devices/services.py", line 181, in dev_execute_cmd
    return HTTPResponse(output, content_type='application/json')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/Users/Documents/Project/<proj>/<dir>/devices/services.py", line 132, in dev_execute_cmd
    uid, last_cmd, mode)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/Users/Documents/Project/<proj>/<dir>/devices/managers.py", line 260, in async_dev_execute_cmd
    # return False if max connections have been exceeded
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/Users/Documents/Project/<proj>/<dir>/devices/managers.py", line 122, in async_open_connection
    ip_addr_conn_count = self.per_dev_conn_count.get(device.ip_addr, 0) + 1
KeyError: '10.32.255.80'
```

My question is - how is a key error using `.get()` possible? In what scenarios can this happen? One thing I have noticed is that this error only occurs when I'm running concurrent requests albeit rarely.

In my understanding, asyncio uses an event loop so it schedules tasks and pauses tasks as it waits. So in my mind, 2+ concurrent requests should never really hit the same dictionary at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check the type of `self.per_dev_conn_count` ?

Comment: Mmm you may want to check for *.pyc files as [this answer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861856/python-dict-get-raises-keyerror)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre good point! I did check it and it is constantly saying `<type 'dict'>` :/ 

@Freddier I'll check on that! But I had deleted all the .pyc files before so I don't think that'll be it. But I'll double check

Comment: strange! I would `print(self.per_dev_conn_count)` just before the faulty line.

Comment: Yea I did that as well in my debugging process - i printed the dictionary before the faulty line and after. totally fine. (shows an un-updated state before and updated state after) 

It is just that on occasion, and only when doing concurrent actions in Asyncio, I get this error. super weird...

Comment: Are you using asyncio.gather() by any chance? Some of asyncio is not thread safe.